# How is the boolean value returned true or false from this statement

Tags: javascript

```
function compare(a, b) {
    return isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) ? a > b : +a > +b;
}
var c  =  compare(10,5);
alert("C value ==?"+c);
```

I'm having trouble in understanding the above script. How is the Boolean value `true` or `false` returned from the compare(). How is the Boolean value generated `true` formed. Please explain.

Comment: Is the condition written correctly? It appears to say that if either a or b are not numbers, return true if a is greater than b which doesn't seem to make sense, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) ? a > b : +a > +b;
```

This checks to see if either `a` or `b` is not a number (`IsNan`). If either test is true, it returns the result of `a > b`; if neither of them is a NAN, it returns the result of `+a > +b`. Read the docs for Javascript's [ternary](http://books.google.com/books?id=vJGlu9t9LNYC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=javascript%20ternary%20op&source=bl&ots=pgYceXA7Q0&sig=6A0GF2WG4bAtYu0FWtYmW_vBU_0&hl=en&ei=p3PUTaCVJojBtAalz7XkAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=javascript%20ternary%20op&f=false) (conditional) operator.

To make sure it's clear, the test is:

> if a is not a number or b is not a
>   number, return true if a is greater
>   than b, otherwise try to convert a and
>   b both to numbers and return whether
>   a is greater than b

Note that the entire expression makes no sense, as it wants to return equality tests for what are possibly not numbers even after the attempted conversion.

Comment: That isn't quite correct. The `+` operator is overloaded, in the OP's context it is acting as *the unary plus operator* (ECMA-262 §11.4.6). It converts the following identifier to a number (if it can), it does not necessarily convert it to a positive value.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks for the correction. I'll try and correct my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Well the return statement has two possible ways to return a value and both of them are boolean:

```
return isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) ? a > b : +a > +b;
```

Could return this (a boolean)

```
isNaN(a)
```

Or this (also a boolean - it is a comparison operator)

```
+a > +b;
```

Comment: It will not return `isNan(a)`. That expression is only evaluated for the sake of determining whehter to return either the result of `a > b` or `+a > +b`.

Answer (score 1):

This is plain javascript (not jQuery) code.

This can be rewritten as

```
if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
   return a > b;
} else {
   return +a > +b;
}
```

If any of the parameters is not a number (if clause), then the function will still try to do some comparison and return the result. Otherwise it will coerce them into numbers, then compare them. Maybe the order of the parameters should be changed...

Comment: Is there any mention of jQuery anywhere? :)

Comment: @alex: The question was originally tagged with `jquery` and `jquery-ui`.